# calculate inclined ellipse semi axes that is inscribed in a parallelogram at the mid points

Tags: conic-sections, parametric

I'm working on a function in c++ to find the semi-major-axis 'a' and semi-minor-axis 'b' of an inclined ellipse that is inscribed in a parallelogram ABCD, where AB is parallel to CD and BC is parallel to AD, and the ellipse is touching the middle points of each side of the parallelogram.
[Ellipse inscribed in parallelogram touching the mid points of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lUqk.png)

The input parameters are :

- Two points p1(x1,y1) and p2(x2,y2) that touches the perimeter of the ellipse at the mid points of segments AB for p1 and AD for p2.
- The center of the ellipse p0(x0,y0).
- The angle from the center (x0,y0) to the point (x1,y1) called B:[-Pi,Pi].
- The angle from the center (x0,y0) to the point (x2,y2) called C:[-Pi,Pi].

So the function looks like this:

```
std::pair<double ,double> calculateEllipseSemiAxes(Point p0, Point p1, Point p2, double A, double B, double C) 
{
  double a; //semi-major axis
  double b, //semi-minor axis

  //find a and b ...

  return {a,b};
}
```

The inclined ellipse equations I've presented before doesn't work for me cause I want to be able to create the points for an arc of the ellipse from p1 to p2 so now I'm using these equations:

```
//parameters
auto angle       = ellipseParameters.angleBegin;
const auto x0    = ellipseParameters.center.x;
const auto y0    = ellipseParameters.center.y;
const auto ab    = ellipseParameters.a * ellipseParameters.b;
const auto asq   = ellipseParameters.a * ellipseParameters.a;
const auto bsq   = ellipseParameters.b * ellipseParameters.b;
auto inclination = ellipseParameters.inclinationAngle;

//variables
double totalAngle, cosAngle, sinAngle, rAngle;
cosAngle = std::cos(angle);
sinAngle = std::sin(angle);
totalAngle = angle + inclination;

//inclined ellipse equations
rAngle = ab / std::sqrt( asq * sinAngle * sinAngle + bsq * cosAngle * cosAngle );

 //results
 auto x = x0 + rAngle * std::cos(totalAngle); //for x coord
 auto y = y0 + rAngle * std::sin(totalAngle); //for y coord
```

Comment: Your  system of equations is over-determined. You have only two unknowns but four equations. Which of the parameters should also be determined by the c++ function? The center? The angles B and C? The four equations seem to be set up correctly, so let us know which four variables are your unknowns.

Comment: My problem evolved since a few weeks ago so I've updated the question with the new info. 
The inclined ellipse equations was hard to find for me so hopefully this will help others too.